# Can't create new database connection in sql developer Even with connection type :Basic and Role: Default or SYSDBA

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Even with connection type :Basic and Role: Default or SYSDBA . 
Error found:

> Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Answer (score 0):

issue these commands and post the ouput

```
lsnrctl stop
lsnrctl start
lsnrctl status
lsnrctl service
set
```

i had this problem while ago. i am guessing you have a virtual machine installed